# Threat result of POST petition with html

Tags: php, html, post, http-post

I have a key validation process with html + php.
I read user's data, then send post petition:

```
<form action="http://ip/keys.php" method="post">
```

Then I read post with php, evaluate it with my db and return a number, depending on the error or 1 if validated.

The problem is, if I send the post to php, after clicking on the html's button:

```
<div class="button">
            <button type="submit">Send your message</button>
</div>
```

html form goes to a blank page with a number written on top left. How to thread this number without changing html form, then depending on which number was it I'll do whatever I want.

--EDIT

my html header looks like this:

```
<form action="http://54.186.92.18/Pixel-Matrix/keys.php" method="post">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <div class="logo">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <label id="logo"</label>
        <!--<label for="name">Type:</label>-->
    </div>
    <div class="right">
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  It *sounds like* you want to use AJAX to fetch a single value from the server, but you're making it seem a lot more complicated.

Comment: @David Never used ajax. With c++ I got the packet back after post petition then I could evaluate which value is returned. With html I don't know how to get this value

Comment: I'm not sure what C++ has to do with anything here.  The terminology you're using is also a bit unclear.  In any case, if there's a server-side resource ("page" of some sort) which expects a form post and returns a single value, then it sounds like you want to make an AJAX request to that resource instead of displaying it in the browser.  There are many introductory tutorials to AJAX available online.

Comment: blank page; check for errors on PHP and db. `if(){...} else { something went South }`

Comment: I have just searched ajax while waiting for answer, sounds like it might be helpfull as you said but If you could give me a little example about how to use it to communicate with my php script, I would mark it as accepted answer

Comment: @Fred-ii- there are no errors, it is a blank page because php script only does: echo "num: " . $num

Comment: how do we know you are using error checking?

Comment: @Fred-ii- who cares? this is not what the question is about

Comment: question's unclear then. wait for someone to post an answer then, I'll pass on this. *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Things :

- As i read from comments you need AJAX code to retrive value from db, here's it.

First file - First.html(AJAX code is in **script** tag)

```
    <html> <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str) {
if (str=="") {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","second.php?q="+str);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script></head>
<body>
<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Nirav Madariya</option>
<option value="2">Nirav Patel</option>
</select></form><br />
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
</body> </html>
```

abother file : second.php

```
<?
$q=$_GET["q"];
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db("test", $con);
$sql="SELECT * FROM client_mast WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>City</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach($row as $value){
  echo "<td>";
  echo $value;  
  echo "</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I'm fetching information of person stored in Database using drop down in HTML.

Comment: how to link js on a different file? my html looks like:
<form action="http://54.186.92.18/Pixel-Matrix/keys.php" method="post">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
 <div class="logo">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <label id="logo"</label>
  <!--<label for="name">Type:</label>-->
 </div>
 <div class="right">

Comment: as you are passing value to another php page with post petition, what you need to retrive from db??

Comment: php checks if you have validations left, then it returns 1 if you can activate your product or another number to specify an error

Comment: I don't know what I need, I just want to get this number, that was my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108196/discussion-between-nirav-madariya-and-dani-roca).